# Jquery - (if css = A) do B

Tags: jquery, css

i'm trying to code the following: in my HTML i have 3 divs with individual id.
div1 is displayed whereas div2 and div3 are not.
I want to swap the visiblity of the blocks by clicking on arrows. Clicking on the arrow on the right would change the visibility of #div1 and #div2 (div1 would not be displayed and div2 would be displayed).
However I cannot manage the if/else in my jquery.

this is the code i currently use:

CSS

```
#vid2, #vid3 {display: none;}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#arrowright").click(function(){
    if($("div#vid1").css("display" "block")) {
        $("div#vid1").css("display" "none");
        $("div#vid2").css("display" "block");
    }
    else if($("div#vid2").css("display" "block")) {
        $("div#vid2").css("display" "none");
        $("div#vid3").css("display" "block");
    }
    else {
        $("div#vid3").css("display" "none");
        $("div#vid1").css("display" "block");
});
```

I have already tried the following:

```
if ($("#vid1").css("display") == "block") {
```

Comment: That code does not even parse correctly. Fix the syntax errors (there are at least 3 different syntax error types in the example) before trying to do anything else.

Comment: Have you tried `===` instead of `==`, or forcing lower case the the property?

Comment: `elseif` is invalid. It should be `else if`

Comment: Could you add some example HTML?

Comment: Also, you have unended parentheses on the `if` and `else if` statements.

Comment: @m_callens `===` will not fix anything; it can be more strict, matching a subset, but never more lax.

Comment: I don't think this is the best way to accomplish this, but if you correct the source errors you can get something that works: https://jsfiddle.net/z3osu3g5/

Comment: @ Jason Sperske: 
html
<div id="vidgallery">
 <video id="vid1" controls poster="../../img/home/home.png">
    <source src="../../vid/vidfr.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
   <video id="vid2" controls poster="">
    <source src="../../vid/vid4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
   <video id="vid3" controls poster="../../img/home/home.png">
    <source src="../../vid/vidyt.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
   </div><!-- #vidgallery -->
   <div id="arrowright">
   <img src="../../img/glass.png">
   </div>
   <div id="arrowleft">
   <img src="../../img/glass.png">
   </div>

Comment: can it work with an <img> instead of a <button>?

Comment: What you have 'already tried', is in fact how you would do what you are trying to do.

Comment: @nootaku this code will work on any element with the `id="arrowright"` and without a default click behavior that would take you off the page (an `a` element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're already using jQuery, you can make the code a little simpler and easier to read with `hide()`, `show()` and `:visible`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#vid2, #vid3').hide();
  $('#arrowright').click(function() {
    if ($('#vid1').is(':visible')) {
      $('#vid1').hide();
      $('#vid2').show();
    } else if ($('#vid2').is(':visible')) {
      $('#vid2').hide();
      $('#vid3').show();
    } else {
      $('#vid3').hide();
      $('#vid1').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="vid1">vid1</div>
<div id="vid2">vid2</div>
<div id="vid3">vid3</div>
<button id="arrowright">arrowright</button>
```

Comment: @JasonSperske don't know why but the copy-paste of your code works for my page as well.